# Passing a class object as a reference parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
Class node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = node(10)


def test(start):
    start.root = node(10)


def test1(start):
    start = 1

b = B()
test(b) # b.root is now assigned to node(10)
test1(b.root) # b.root is still None
```

I want to put like b.root.left or b.root.left.left or b.root.right 
If I use the test function I can only assing to b.root.
But using test1 function did not update the parameter.

Comment: after running test function b.root changed to a new value

Comment: while running test1 function did not change the value of b.root

Comment: can I know how to change the value of b.root while using test1 function cause I want to put different parameter like b.root.left or b.root.left.right

Comment: @eyllanesc https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/YRuVKOaZtvY4F7Fsl9JiWA

Comment: I have not asked for a link, I have clearly asked for a MRE

Comment: do you mean: `def test1(start):  start.root.left = 5`.  when you `test1(b);print(b.root.left)`, it should be 5.  is that what you're asking?  or `def test1(root):  root.left = 5`.  then call `test1(b.root)`